# Localhost slow on desktop, not on laptop

Tags: apache-http-server, php, localhost

I am using XAMPP Lite on my desktop and laptop, which uses Apache for the web-server and also supports PHP.

My locally hosted image gallery PHP program has its page elements (100s of thumbnails) rendered instantly on my laptop - as it should - but seems to take as long as it would online, on my desktop.

Can anyone explain this? I suspect this may be a port issue. I haven't tried reinstalling XAMPP yet, however.

EDIT: I changed the Apache port to 81 and the problem persists.

Comment: What's the difference in hardware between the two systems?  Memory, hard drive speeds, CPU, etc, could all contribute to vastly different performance.

Comment: Oh the laptop is really a larger netbook. The hardware in my desktop is incomparably more powerful than my laptop.

Comment: OS differences?

Comment: Note that i had similar problem with speed on my Win7 comp while others did not have on their XP's, but it went away on it's own. I thought surely an update to windows could have repaired it...

Comment: No both same Windows 7 Prof. I've tried everything google has to offer so far. Both are updated regularly too.

Comment: You never gave hardware specifics, so I'm still leaning towards hardware limits.  I'm going to guess you've got more stuff running on the desktop, eating up CPU/memory, and maybe even causing excessive head seek on the HDD.  Alternatively, perhaps the laptop has an SSD while the desktop has a spinning disk, and the webapp is disk limited.

Comment: ok so in the end I just moved to WAMP instead of XAMPP. Now it runs instantly like it should. Strange. Thanks anyway.